# data cleansing icon not in toolbar

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-quality-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I installed SQL Server 2012 - Enterprise Edition with Data Quality Services.

Now, I want to use data quality services, data cleansing task from a package in Integration services. The problem is I can't find the task in the toolbar. Do I have to install an add-on for visual studio or sql server data tools?

[image]

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DQS Cleansing is a DataFlow component so it only shows up when you are in the DataFlow tab...

[image]